# Using forms_for with Rails cells gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cells

I create Wall component using cells gem. And use next code to render form inside `app/cells/wall/show.haml`

```
= form_for :messagess do |f|
  = f.text_field :test
```

but output contain

```
<form action="http://test.localhost:3000/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="0OScxNnGoB47HW4YNIJ2ERhSDcPCcEbEGflI8Wq05FC0ny6XuYh4rWwHY5nOigXDIGZRJqg1HLN1OQ2J4CVEEw==" />
    &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;messagess[test]&quot; id=&quot;messagess_test&quot; /&gt;
</form>
```

What I do wrong?